# How to send new request to redirect URL with new access token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dotnet-httpclient

I have been asked to create a simple MVC web page to help our security officer test one of our web sites.

The page allows the user to enter a new ID and a new access token before attempting to access the URL. The security officer has valid credentials and is able to obtain his access token via a tool called Zap.

I always get the same response from the server:
"Response status code does not indicate success: 401"

What am I doing wrong?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AOFun(RequestValues requestValues)
    {
        try
        {
            string id = requestValues.id;
            string accessToken = requestValues.accessToken;
            string url =
            @"https://companyDomain/api/api/pl/redirect-url?&vendorSystem=false&action=5&id={{idValue}}&app=ONE"
            .Replace("{{idValue}}", id);

            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                var responseData = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                responseData.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseString = await responseData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ResponseModel rm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(responseString);
                ViewBag.ResponseString = rm.url;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ResponseString = "error: " + ex.Message;
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

edit to show the response from POSTMAN

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "code": 5001,
    "message": "There was a problem processing this request. We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please contact the Help Desk or try again later.",
    "htmlMessage": "There was a problem processing this request. We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please contact the Help Desk at 1-800-000-0000 or try again later.",
    "link": "http://www.companyDomain.com",
    "developerMessage": "IGNORE_STACK_TRACE:pl/redirect-url"
}
```

postman request headers:

```
var client = new     
RestClient("https://agentsonly.msagroup.com/api/api/pl/redirect-url?vendorSystem=false&action=5&id=920287945119&app=ONE&=");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader("Host", "agentsonly.msagroup.com");
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "e27138a6-425c-4d11-a09a-0625daeb22a3,8439731b-3dad-464c-9b86-0655da31ead7");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 965c59f9-3f06-370d-8980-764576136e4e");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

postman response headers:
[image]

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the code you've posted should work just fine. Can you use Insomnia/Postman using one of the access tokens, and submit a GET request directly to the URL to verify that the access token is actually correct? It might contain the wrong audience, clientId, clientSecret, etc.

Comment: @Adrrei - i added the postman response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated controller method is below. In the case of this site, I Should not have used a Bearer token. I had to send a User ID for the token to be applied to.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> AOFun(RequestValues requestValues)
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
            string userID = requestValues.userId;
            string id = requestValues.id;
            string accessToken = requestValues.accessToken;
            string url =
            @"https://companydomain.com/api/api/pl/redirect-url?&vendorSystem=false&action=5&id={{idValue}}&app=ONE"
            .Replace("{{idValue}}", id);
            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("userId", userID);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("access_token", accessToken);
                var responseData = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                responseData.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseString = await responseData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ResponseModel rm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(responseString);
                ViewBag.ResponseString = rm.url;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ResponseString = "error: " + ex.Message;
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the code inside the `AOFun` action - the request never gets there.

The response indicates that your request is not authenticated - perhaps the token you've used has expired. So you have to start a new session and log in to generate a fresh token. Then put that fresh token in the header to the `AOFun` request..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Th Security Officer logs into the site the first time and then retrieves the access Token using a tool called Zap. That token is good for 14 hours. Should I do something else other than use that token ?

Comment: Nope. Just remember to put the word _Bearer_ and a space before the token as you did in the C# code above. Maybe you need to revise the security filters if any and/or the authentication setup. Are you using ASP.NET Identity? How it is initialized? Post your code, please...

Comment: The code posted in this question is all of the code I have. Which is why I asked if I need something else other than this.